# Google manual action removed but effects remain similar

Tags: seo, google, google-search, penalty

Our domain had been under Google manual action penalty until recently. 
One week ago we finally get the action removed.

However, we made a test creating a new domain  and pointing it to the existing website. In one week new domain have 3 times more pages indexed than the domain we removed the action.

So, yes, action is removed and performance is a little improved. But why is it still under some kind of handicap, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: what's the manual action exactly? and what are the domain names in question?

Comment: Manual actions can take quite some time before they really go away. Some effects can remain for a fairly long time. Remember that a manual action is essentially the most severe of the all penalties. It is not algorithmic and can  effect a domains trust score.

Comment: @Mike It was thin content, but thin content was in the website which this domain was pointing in the past.

Comment: @closetnoc Do you think a domain can remove all the effects eventually? (assuming that the website is completely compatible with webmaster guidelines)

Comment: Thin content? That should have been algorithmic and not manual. However, you should recover from this just fine. It will just take time. How much time?? I have no clue. However, it can take up to about 10 months though less likely.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that if you got to the stage of a manual action being taken that some other algorithmic actions where already taken. In addition if a Google algorithm update was pushed out while you where under manual review then your rank afterwards may be different to what it was  previously. As has been mentioned in the comments a manual action review can affect a domains trust score and even when the manual action review is removed the trust score won't automatically go back up again it will need to go up over time with valuable content and other positive things that naturally increase the trust score. I would urge you to get rid of the second domain you created as not only will it be detected for duplicate content with your main domain but it may also be deemed an attempt to circumvent Google's reduced trust score on your domain which will affect the new domain as well, and may even reduce the domain trust for your first primary domain.

It will take some time but after 6-12 months you should see things on the rise again, perhaps even less if your site does have very valuable and unique content deemed of value to end users.